# Has anyone else encountered gui-get-selection: (error "Timed out...") bug?

Tags: linux

When trying to paste into Emacs from my Linux system GUI, I'm getting
a 10-15 second Emacs freeze and:

```
gui-get-selection: (error "Timed out waiting for reply from selection owner")
```

I would post a bug, except I can't pin-point the condition to
reliably reproduce the bug. Has anyone else encountered this?
I'm on GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1.

Comment: Are you using any clipboard manager? Last time I had this, it was Emacs fighting over the selection ownership with the one I was using.

Comment: No clipboard managers.

Comment: At least for Emacs builds on WSL, [this hack](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/4tpn5r/running_emacs_master_branch_in_recent_wsl_and/) helped!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer: yes (also with 25.0.50.1).

This might be related to emacs bug 16737.

Try running (shell-command-to-string "xclip -o"). When I attempt this (once emacs has started misbehaving with respect to any attempt to yank), emacs hangs until I kill xclip.

Comment: I can reproduce this.

Comment: It looks like there are actually a few bug reports probably related to this that have been merged: 16737 17026 17101 17172 (see debbugs.gnu.org for some of the details -- doesn't look like there are any happy endings yet...).

Answer (score 0):

The error message indeed seems to come form xclip! If running 'xclip -o' after a fresh reboot, (i.e. when the clipboard is still empty, ) then the error message appears (gui-get-selection: (error "Timed out waiting for reply from selection owner")).

Workaround: Ctrl+C anything